# Trying to make a test app with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ with REST API

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to make a test app with 4 users and whenever some user is clicked, it should go to next activity and show that Users info and all his posts by implementing REST API from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/.

I'm new to this. Any help/example on how to do that?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Move to the Activity using Intent when the button is clicked. Save the user info into the Intent so that the next Activity can retrieve it and make a request based on the selected user info.
2. Make a network request to the mockup site you mention using their corresponding APIs. There are several ways to do it. You can use rather the default HttpUrlConnection from Android or libraries such as okhttp, retrofit2, and etc.
3. Parse the json data you receive. You have a lot of options for this too. You can use default JsonParser from Java or libraries such as gson.
4. Then manipulate and show the data within your predesigned XML layout.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will do exactly as you said.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do this exact thing. Could you please shared the code

Comment: @jvargas Obviously there's no free lunch ;) but you can still look into sample apps here https://developer.android.com/samples or code uploaded in github. These are really basic stuff so I'd rather suggest you to take some online courses on Android at sites like Udacity.

Comment: @jvargas oh maybe you were asking ajzaklija not me, but yeah.